# Drupal 8 Double Field HTML

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-8

I'm using Drupal 8, and the [Double Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/double_field) module. I want for the second field to allow HTML tags, but currently the tags are directly output on the page as text. There is no field format that would not escape HTML tags.

In the issues for this module, [the author suggests "overriding theme_double_field()"](https://www.drupal.org/node/2572483), but I don't know how to go about that.

How can I enable HTML tags for the second field of a double field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, all strings in twig templates are escaped. That's why you lose your formatting. You can avoid this in 2 ways:

1. Use [`FormattableMarkup`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Component%21Render%21FormattableMarkup.php/class/FormattableMarkup/8.2.x) in preprocess function to pass formattable string variable to your twig template.
2. Use `raw` filter in twig template.

`Double Field` provides several formatters, but suppose you use the simplest `Unformatted list` formatter, which uses `double_field_item` theme to render double field item.

Then the first solution is to write your own preprocess function for `double_field_item` theme:

```
use Drupal\Component\Render\FormattableMarkup;

function mytheme_preprocess_double_field_item(&$variables) {
  $item = $variables['elements']['#item'];
  $second_value = new FormattableMarkup($item->second, []);
  $variables['item']['second'] = $second_value;
}
```

And the alternative second solution is to override `double-field-item.html.twig` template in your theme:

```
{% for subfield, subitem in item %}
    {% if subitem %}
        <div class="double-field-{{ subfield }}">
            {% if settings[subfield].prefix %}
                <span class="double-field-prefix">{{ settings[subfield].prefix }}</span>
            {% endif %}
            {{ subitem|raw }}
            {% if settings[subfield].suffix %}
                <span class="double-field-suffix">{{ settings[subfield].suffix }}</span>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Choose any :)

Comment: Amazing; the first solution worked like a charm! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears there is [support in the works](https://www.drupal.org/node/2091587), but that the patch isn't ready for inclusion in the module yet. Your best option is likely to help finish work on the patch.

Comment: There is no way to override the display of the double field data via theme functions or overriding module templates in the theme?